# Swift - #selector methods not being called

Tags: ios, swift

I have UIBarButtonItem and the selector method is not being called, been driving me nuts for days.

These are in my viewDidLoad method

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.doneButtonPressed))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
        
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.cancelButtonPressed))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
```

and here are the methods:

```
@objc func doneButtonPressed()
{
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func cancelButtonPressed()
{
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How come they are not being called?

Comment: Set 'target' to self instead of nil

Comment: I knew it was being stupid and was missing something, if you put that in an answer ill accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You should set `target` to self instead of `nil`

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonPressed))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a valid `target` in `UIBarButtonItem(title:style:target:action:)`.

This is how it works behind the scenes: `#selector` transforms your selector into a `Selector` type: something that is almost – but not quite – a string. The Objective C runtime later uses that `Selector` to send a message with the Selector as its content to `target`; i.e. it *calls* the selector on the target.

Therefore, you **must** add the `@objc` annotation to your target and you **must** add the target to the constructor.